# Как отключить выполнение скрипта в одном месте, после запуска его в другом?

Tags: javascript

Вот например, я запустил этот скрипт, он отрабатывает нормально, потом он запускается еще раз при запуске другого скрипта, и в том месте, где считало правильно, он начинает отсчитывать неправильно. Как отключить выполнение этого скрипта в первый раз?

```
var click_no = function () {
    $('.b-rewiews__answer-no').bind("click", function() {
         var par = $(this).parent().find('.b-rewiews__number-no');
         var child = par.html();
         par.html(parseInt(child) + 1);
    });
 };

click_no(); // сделайте сразу вызов, после объявления.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Первый скрипт
var clickHandler = function() {
        //...
    },
    click_no = function () {
        $('.b-rewiews__answer-no').bind("click", clickHandler);
    };

// Функция должна быть глобально видна для другого скрипта 
// и не должна перетираться во втором скрипте
window.unbind_click_no = function() {
    $('.b-rewiews__answer-no').unbind("click", clickHandler);
};

click_no();

// В другом скрипте перед вызовом click_no()

unbind_click_no();
click_no();
```

Comment: начинает считать неправильно, при каждом клике добавляет по 2

Comment: использовал $('.b-rewiews__answer-no').unbind("click", clickHandler); в скрипте где вызывается вновь и норм работает! Спасибо.